# Error on locating local flutter package in another folder

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

i created a flutter package using the command

```
flutter create --template=package my_query
```

And it works fine, now i wanna use this package on my other application.

I added my package on the dependecies and also the path

```
dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter
   my_new_package:
     path: ./Users/Name/Desktop/Flutter/my_query
```

error message:

```
pub get failed (66; Because flutter_email depends on couch_db from path 
which doesn't exist (could not find package couch_db at 
"‪./Users/Name/Desktop/Flutter/my_query"), version solving failed.)
exit code 66
```

This is the directory of my package
`C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Flutter\my_query`

How to do the path correctly?

Comment: Your path is relative to the current folder because it starts with a `.`. Looks like your system is macOS, if you want it to be absolute you should start with `/`. BUT a correct relative path is better when sharing the code.

Answer (score 1):

try to set the path to your package in relation to the location of your pubspec.yaml file.

E.g. if your folder `flutter-projects` contains a folder with `flutter-app` and your package `my-query`, try referencing `my-query` in your pubspec.yaml like this:

`dependencies:
  my-query:
    path: ../my-query`

Let me know if this solved your issue!